# android login/registration missing toast response after connection to server

Tags: java, php, android, authentication, registration

I have read many post on this issue, however my application works fine (compiles and runs). When I enter information for the register page and hit the register button, I see the "registering...." message, but the toast message is empty and I see this message in my logcat:

03-21 11:24:50.350  12422-12422/info.androidhive.loginandregistration E/RegisterActivity﹕ Registration Error: null

I am using wamp as my server and here is the java, and manifest code.

```
 package info.androidhive.loginandregistration;

 import info.androidhive.loginandregistration.app.AppConfig;import  
 info.androidhive.loginandregistration.app.AppController;
 import info.androidhive.loginandregistration.helper.SQLiteHandler;
 import info.androidhive.loginandregistration.helper.SessionManager;

 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.Map;

 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
 import com.android.volley.Response;
 import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
 import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private Button btnRegister;
private Button btnLinkToLogin;
private EditText inputFullName;
private EditText inputEmail;
private EditText inputPassword;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private SessionManager session;
private SQLiteHandler db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);

    // Progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // Session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    // SQLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if user is already logged in or not
    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,
                MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    // Register Button Click event
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

            if (!name.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) 

    {
                registerUser(name, email, password);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });

    // Link to Login Screen
    btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Function to store user in MySQL database will post params(tag, name,
 * email, password) to register url
 * */
  private void registerUser(final String name, final String email,
                          final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_register";

    pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                if (!error) {
                    // User successfully stored in MySQL
                    // Now store the user in sqlite
                    String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    String created_at = user
                            .getString("created_at");

                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                    // Launch login activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            RegisterActivity.this,
                            LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {

                    // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                    // message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("tag", "register");
            params.put("name", name);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}

private void showDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
}


 AndroidManifest

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="info.androidhive.loginandregistration"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name="info.androidhive.loginandregistration.app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

---

```
 Index.php

<?php

/**
* File to handle all API requests
* Accepts GET and POST
* 
* Each request will be identified by TAG
* Response will be JSON data

 /**
* check for POST request 
*/
if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
// get tag
$tag = $_POST['tag'];

// include db handler
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

  // response Array
 $response = array("tag" => $tag, "error" => FALSE);

 // check for tag type
 if ($tag == 'login') {
    // Request type is check Login
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // check for user
    $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);
    if ($user != false) {
        // user found
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
        $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user not found
        // echo json with error = 1
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
   } else if ($tag == 'register') {
    // Request type is Register new user
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // check if user is already existed
    if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
        // user is already existed - error response
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed";
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // store user
        $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);
        if ($user) {
            // user stored successfully
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
            $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user failed to store
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Registartion";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
 } else {
    // user failed to store
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Unknow 'tag' value. It should be either    
         'login' or 'register'";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
```

---

```
Config.php

<?php

/**
* Database config variables
*/
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_DATABASE", "android_api");
?>
```

---

```
DB_Connect.php

<?php
class DB_Connect {

// constructor
function __construct() {

}

// destructor
function __destruct() {
    // $this->close();
}

// Connecting to database
public function connect() {
    require_once 'include/Config.php';
    // connecting to mysqli
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or    
                 die(mysqli_error());
    // selecting database
    mysqli_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_error());

    // return database handler
    return $con;
 }

  // Closing database connection
  public function close() {
    mysqli_close();
  }
```

---

DB_Functions.php

```
<?php

class DB_Functions {

private $db;

//put your code here
// constructor
function __construct() {
    require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
    // connecting to database
    $this->db = new DB_Connect();
    $this->db->connect();
}

// destructor
function __destruct() {

}

/**
 * Storing new user
 * returns user details
 */
public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
    $result = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email,    encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");
    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        // get user details 
        $uid = mysqlii_insert_id(); // last inserted id
        $result = mysqlii_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
        // return user details
        return mysqlii_fetch_array($result);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Get user by email and password
 */
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {
    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'") or die(mysqli_error());
    // check for result 
    $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $salt = $result['salt'];
        $encrypted_password = $result['encrypted_password'];
        $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
        // check for password equality
        if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
            // user authentication details are correct
            return $result;
        }
    } else {
        // user not found
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Check user is existed or not
 */
public function isUserExisted($email) {
    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT email from users WHERE email =        '$email'");
    $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        // user existed 
        return true;
    } else {
        // user not existed
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Encrypting password
 * @param password
 * returns salt and encrypted password
 */
public function hashSSHA($password) {

    $salt = sha1(rand());
    $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
    $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
    $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
    return $hash;
}

/**
 * Decrypting password
 * @param salt, password
 * returns hash string
 */
public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

    $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

    return $hash;
}

}

?>

Thank you.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be with the blank userName and password in `Config.php`.

Please supply the user details in those fields.